# OAuth 2.0 authorization performance in postgres

Tags: api, security, postgresql, rest, oauth

I'm developing a RESTful API and I have implemented OAuth 2.0 authorization.

All my clients make requests passing the bearer token in the Authorization header over SSL:

```
Authorization: Bearer sdflksd3r4823vgbyerge
```

Currently I am saving access tokens and refresh tokens in Postgres, so in every request the server has to connect to the db and execute a SELECT query. The 'tokens' table contains about a million rows, so **performance is not very good**, even if the table is indexed... I also think that checking for token validity on every request is quite a waste of time.

Our tokens now are just random bytes of data. We considered using self-encoded tokens, so that tokens can be decoded and validated without a database lookup, but the problem is that tokens must be **revocable** from users, so this is not a solution.

What are my options?

I was thinking of using **Redis** instead of Postgres: reads should be much faster.
Another option could be to check token validity, **cache the response** in Memcached for 15 minutes, so subsequent requests don't require a db lookup.

Any ideas?

Comment: The phrase "performance is not very good" doesn't actually tell us much. What times are you seeing to look up a token? Why is the server connecting to the database just for this one query? Something like memcache is perfect for checking auth tokens though.

Comment: Hi @RichardHuxton before implementing oauth a 'typical request' to my api had a response time of 0.200 seconds...now the same request takes about 0.800 seconds. obviously these response times aren't bad, they're ok...but i want to at least try and reduce them so i was thinking that maybe postgres isn't the best solution for storing tokens...

Comment: 600ms doesn't sound right for a simple query. Can't say for sure though since you haven't provided any hard figures or details of your setup. If you've got a $5/yr box running on a different continent from your application then it's quite fast.

Comment: @RichardHuxton i'm using an ec2 micro instance, the db is on the same machine as the application server

Answer (score 3):

I've tried gently prodding for some real figures. Since you're not prepared to say what your "ec2 micro instance" actually has in terms of usable GHz/RAM/disk I/O we'll have to try it another way.

```
CREATE TABLE tokens(tok text, username text);
INSERT INTO tokens SELECT md5(i::text), 'User number ' || i FROM generate_series(1,1000000) i;
SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE username LIKE '%01' LIMIT 19;
-- Now check the timings on some of returned tokens
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT username FROM tokens WHERE tok = '38b3eff8baf56627478ec76a704e9b52';
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using tokens_pkey on tokens  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.099..0.101 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (tok = '38b3eff8baf56627478ec76a704e9b52'::text)
 Total runtime: 0.133 ms
(3 rows)
```

As you can see - mine is running so fast that the timing is probably meaningless. If I cared, then I'd run 10000 from 10 parallel processes with random waits between. I don't - it's less than 1ms and even on the slowest virtual-machine I'd expect < 5ms.

So - is the issue with your application? Can't tell - you didn't give details.

Is it your framework? Can't tell - you wouldn't say.

Is it connection time? Can't tell...

Is it the query itself? Can't tell...

What it isn't though, is any problem that PostgreSQL has reading a single row from a *tiny* 1 million row table using an index.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll check my code again and post any updates!

Comment: Hi @Richard-Huxton I finally solved the problem: the bug was in the application server, not in the Postgres query! I can now extract a row from a 2-million table in less than 3ms. So Postgres performance is no longer an issue.
Now....back to the original question! Is this the right thing to do? Is executing a query on the db every time a client makes a request right? Would it make sense to cache the result of the query in memcache? Or perhaps not use a db at all and use a nosql instead? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do the simplest thing that works. Query the database until it's a problem, then add a simple cache. No point having two database systems unless you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that there should be an index on the token, which Richard's response omitted. Prior to creating the index, my query run time was ~200 ms. After creating the index, it dropped to 0.1 ms. (Sorry, I'd comment on his post directly, but I don't have a high enough score).